# Is the basis of null space of a matrix always a subset of the basis of its column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, is the basis of its null space (set of $x$ such that $Ax=0$) always a subset of the basis of the row space of $A$? In general, the basis of a subspace may not be a subset of the basis of a row space, but is it true if the subspace is specifically the null space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This answer goes with the original question of "is the null space contained in the column space?", but I think it's still worth leaving it here. It does, however contain the answer to the new version of the question of "is the null space contained in the row space?". The answer is that the null space must be orthogonal to the row space and therefore cannot be contained in the row space unless it is just the zero vector.

No it is not always true that the null space is contained in the column space.

For a start, if the matrix is not square, then its null space and column space are in different vector spaces!

For example, consider this $2 \times 3$ matrix:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The column space of $A$ consists of vectors with two coordinates, so the column space is in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The null space consists of vectors with three coordinates (because they have to be able to be the $\mathbf{x}$ in the equation $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$), so the null space is in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Even if the matrix is square, then in general the null space is not contained in the column space. Here are some specific situations that are easy to describe:

Firstly, the dimension of the null space and the dimension of the column space add to the number of columns. So it is perfectly possible for the null space to actually have a larger dimension than the column space, and therefore it can't be contained in the column space.

For example, consider the matrix:
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 2 & -2 \\ 3 & 3 & -3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This has column space spanned by $(1,2,3)^T$ and null space spanned by $(1,0,1)^T$ and $(0,1,1)^T$. Note that $(1,2,3)^T$ actually happens to be in the null space so in this example the column space is actually contained in the null space, though this doesn't always happen either.

Secondly, consider symmetric matrices. These matrices have the same column space as row space. Since the null space is orthogonal to the row space (which is the same as the column space for these matrices), it can't possibly be contained in the column space unless it's just the zero vector!

For example, consider the matrix: 
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This has column space spanned by $(1,1,1)^T$ and $(0,1,0)^T$ and null space spanned by  $(1,0,-1)^T$. Note that $(1,0,-1)$ is not in the column space.

Answer (score 1):

No. Why should a vector $x$ satisfying $Ax=0$  also satisfy $x=Au$ for some $u$?
Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&5\end{bmatrix}$.

**EDIT:** OK, so you rewrote the problem. The nullspace and row space are always orthogonal complements of one another.

Comment: thanks, this also shows null space may not be subspace of column space

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is $m\times n$, the nullspace is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: edited question. recheck.